# Can't write to a file with Django in Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, server, permissions, with-statement

I have deployed a Django web app using uWSGI and Nginx, but the app runs into an error when trying to create a file inside a specified folder.

Inside my views file, I specify a function which writes to a file using "with open". This function writes the file to a folder named 'output' inside the Django project folder. When I run the Django server, all the functionality works well, but, when I run the Nginx server, it gives me an error exactly where the "with open" is.

I have already tried to switch the ownership of the 'output' folder, but it did not work. Also tried to run 'sudo chmod -R www-data:www-data' with my whole project folder as an attribute, but I had no success.

I would please like to have more insight on how to fix this issue. The problem is likely about my permissions, but I have tried everything in my knowledge to fix it but it did not work.

In attachment, I am sending an image of the output of the 'ls -la' command inside my Django project folder.
Also, the guide I have followed can be found here: https://tonyteaches.tech/django-nginx-uwsgi-tutorial/.

```py
# views.py
filename = 'Memorial_LaTeX.tex'
filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'output', filename)
memorial = open(filepath, 'w')
```

It is right at this last line that the exception occurs.

[output of the ls -la command inside my Django project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBm4Y.png)

Comment: Can you update the question with your view's code and the error that you get?

Comment: Of course, just added it,

Comment: Everything seems okay. Try replacing os.getcwd() with BASE_DIR importing it from settings file.

Comment: Yes, got it replaced. However, the problem persists. Could it be a permission error inside the project folder? It appears that the problem only occurs when Django has to write the file while being run by Nginx.